# UIBezierPath - What is unit radius

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I am programming a Swift application, I use the SDK Skobbler to manipulate a map.
The application displays circles:

```
func displayCircle(x: Int, y: Int, radius: Int){...} //display circle in the map
```

Moreover, I check if the user is in this area:

```
for area in self.areas {

            var c = UIBezierPath()

            let lat = area.getLatitude()
            let long = area.getLongitude()
            let radius = area.getRadius()/1000
            let center = CGPoint(x: lat, y: long)

            c.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: CGFloat(radius), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(360), clockwise: true)
            if c.containsPoint(CGPoint(x: currentLocation.latitude, y: currentLocation.longitude)) {
                //I AM IN THE AREA
            }else {
                //I AM NOT IN THE AREA
            }
            c.closePath()  
        }
```

When I am in the circle, it works but, when I am outsite the circles it also works...

I think the problem is related to the unit radius

- skobbler -> unit meter
- UIBezierPath - unit ???

Thank you for your help

Ysee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not answering your question, but you should use `CoreLocation` functions for that task:

```
    let current = CLLocation(latitude: currentLocation.latitude, longitude: currentLocation.longitude)
    for area in self.areas {
        let center = CLLocation(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(area.getLatitude()), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(area.getLongitude()))
        if current.distanceFromLocation(center) <= CLLocationDistance(area.getRadius()) {
            //I AM IN THE AREA
        }
        else {
            //I AM NOT IN THE AREA
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The iOS unit is point.
In non-retina devices, 1 point equals 1 pixel.
In retina devices (@2x) , 1 point equals two pixels.
In @3x devices (Iphone 6 plus) , 1 point equals three pixels.

Care about angles. The unit is radian not degrees.
So you need to convert your degrees To radian, your and angle should be `2 * M_PI` which correspond to 360 deg. you can define an extension to do the conversion:

```
extension Int {
        var degreesToRadians : CGFloat {
             return CGFloat(self) * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0
        }
    }
    45.degreesToRadians   // 0.785398163397448
```